# Ask Background border radius on CSS

Tags: css

How to make background have a border radius like this image:

[image]

Comment: You can't. You will either need to (1) use an SVG image mask or (2) use a static background image for the top of the container. Also, you should always show what you've done so far: even if that means sharing just the markup and rudimentary CSS that you have in hand. StackOverflow is, contrary to popular belief, not a free code writing service.

Comment: Show your html, it may help...

Answer (score 0):

You can use clipping. [Here](https://css-tricks.com/clipping-masking-css/) is a guide.

Answer (score 0):

This is not a border radius nor a background for the top of the container. These seems to me, more like a background of the arrows of the slider.

Most of times, good designs relies on visual tricks AND it's a good practice to inspect webpages that you like and learn from other's code